# jsonpCallback scope trouble

Tags: json, variables, scope, country

I am a complete noob with web development and I have trouble assigning myCountry variable in the following code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
<script>
var myCountry=" "
function jsonpCallback(data) { 
           myCountry=data.address.country;
            }
jsonpCallback();
var countryText="You are from "+myCountry;
        document.getElementById("displaycountry").innerHTML =countryText;
}
</script>
<script src="http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback"
                 type="text/javascript">
                 </script>
</head>
<center>
<p id="displaycountry" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to assign the value of data.address.country to myCountry and use it outside of the function,but the value always remains " ".

The jsonpCallback function displays the country just fine if I use the following code(but I want to be able to modify the position of it in html):

```
function jsonpCallback(data) { 
          a.innerHTML ="<br/>Country: " + data.address.country; 

            }
```

thank you

Comment: The problem is not your JSONP callback, but the fact you don't understand the asynchronous nature of that call. Your assignment of the content from `myCountry` is just to early, so that the callback has had no time to be executed before.

Answer (score 0):

as @Sirko mentioned, the problem is that you're not actually making the call to the Wipmania api, you are trying to use the callback as a QueryString parameter, which will not work by simply putting the request on the `<script>` tag.

Here's what you'll might want to do.

First you'll want to change the label on your callback function, since it will all be executed after the request has retrieved any data:

```
<p id="displaycountry"></p>

<script>
var myCountry = "";

// This is your callback function
function jsonCallback(data) { 
  myCountry = data.address.country;
  var countryText="You are from "+myCountry;
  document.getElementById("displaycountry").innerHTML = countryText;
}

// Do the request
// Code below
</script>
```

Next what you want to do is actually make the call to the api, perhaps using `XMLHttpRequest` from Javascript itself:

```
// This will stablish the Request to the api
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "//api.wipmania.com/json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        jsonCallback(response);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Hope it helps, for more fundamentals into Javascript I recommend some online crash courses, perhaps [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript) is a good place to start.

Cheers